# Validate method

Tags: validation, struts2, struts-validation

i have my Struts2 project, in which there are 2 java beans class : `Account1` and `Account2`. I tried to make new validate in register class, i put it here :

```
public void validate(){

    if( getAccount1().getUsername().length()==0){
        this.addFieldError("account1.username", getText("username.required"));
    }   

    if( getAccount1().getPassword().length()<6){
        this.addFieldError("account1.password", getText("password.short"));
    }   

    if( getAccount1().getPassword().length()<6){
        this.addFieldError("account2.password", getText("password.short"));
    }   

    if( getAccount2().getUsername().length()==0){
        this.addFieldError("account2.username", getText("username.required"));
    }   

}
```

The problem is that when Struts2 try to read this validate it fall in exception... how i can insert `Account 1` and `Account 2` in the way that everyone don't fall in exception?

Comment: you have a typo (two times account1), and you should probably read about the Visitor Validator. The rest of the question is unclear, and the error should be definitely added :/

Comment: Sorry my english, my question is : i want that Account1 (validate) is used while i try to register account1 on webpage with action, and not also account2, in the same way when i try to register a new account2 i want that is used only Account2 validate

Comment: You can use `validateXXX()` method where xxx is method name.

Comment: so i will have 2 validate method?

Comment: Yes, and don't post same question multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having multiple validation functions in a class with multiple actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222955/having-multiple-validation-functions-in-a-class-with-multiple-actions)

Comment: If we speak italian the others won't understand, and SO purpose is to help many users with widely applicable Q&A. BTW it is not clear what are account1 and account2. Do you have a single page allowing one user to register to two different systems ? If so, wouldn't be better to have two separate pages, with two separate actions ?

Comment: i solved with try catch Null Pointer Exception e